# POST data to php controller with DataTables Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post, datatables

I'm trying to use the DataTables library for Jquery to POST some simple data to a controller which is a SQL query. This query will return JSON and I will go on my merry way and then do what I will with the data.

I am having no problems with this when using built in jquery AJAX. Here is the working code:

```
$.post('/rx/dostuff', {fromDate: from_date, toDate: to_date}, function(data){                
            var dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
            if(data !== "[]"){
                $("#display_area").empty();
                $("#display_area").append("<div> " + ...

            blah blah blah
```

So this works great, I POST the from_date and the to_date, and I can see in the Network Params tab that it is being sent as

```
fromDate: 02/01/2016
toDate:   02/24/2016
```

which my PHP controller picks up, I do some statement binding to keep it safe, and boom, my results are returned to me JSON encoded.

When I try to do this using the DataTables library, my params end up being sent like this:

```
fromDate=02%2F01%2F2016&toDate=02%2F24%2F2016
```

PHP raises hell, and throws a warning that I am missing argument 1 for my controller.

My question is, why is DataTables sending the params like this? Have I malformed the way that it is meant to be sent?

Here is my DataTables AJAX code:

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "/rx/dostuff",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: {
                "fromDate": from_date,
                "toDate": to_date
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'col'},
            { data: 'col'},
            { data: 'col'},
            { data: 'col'}
        ]
    });
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `contentType: "application/json"`.

This parameter defines the format when sending data to the server. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" which should be working for you according to what you've used before with `$.post()`.

See [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/) for more information.

Comment: thanks, that was indeed what was causing the weird post params. So simple!